# problems with the user login using sftp. user root works fine

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

i am trying to do a sftp from my user in linux vm.

After i enter my password i get the message: `Connection closed`. When I try to login with the `root` user, it is working fine.

I found that the issue might be in /etc/ssh/sshd_config but changes didnt solve the problem.

How can i change sftp permission so the user is able to use it? Could be the error a wrong target where the user wants to enter? How can i change the sftp target?

Do you have any ideas in how to solve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/passwd` the user is not allowed to have `/rbash` u need to give him bash and use chroot or jail or sth like this!